# Create an `onclick` div without buttons / anchors?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to work out how to make a custom lightbox type thing (I'm making an image gallery / video player which will sit inside a template) for my website but can't seem to work out. How I can make a whole div clickable.

I've tried using an anchor wrapped around the div but that still won't make the div display.

A live version of the page / website which contains the full html can be found here - 
http://mosesmartin.co.uk/digitalguys/ford.php#

the HTML -

```
<a onclick="showdiv('imagepopup');" href="#">
    <div class="rectanglewrap">
        <div class="rectangleimg" id="fordengine">
            <div class="rectangleimginfo">
                <h3 class="imageinfo">Story in Pictures</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#imagepopup {
visibility: hidden;
position:absolute;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background-color: black;
margin-right:0px;
}
```

And the Jquery / Javascript

```
function showdiv(Div_id) {
    if (false == $(Div_id).is(':visible')) {
        $(Div_id).show(250);
    }
    else {
        $(Div_id).hide(250);
    }
}
```

I'm by no means a master at JavaScript so if there's a better way of doing this please let me know.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `display` instead of `visibility` when toggling it?

Comment: Also, as a side note: You're using `jQuery`, so you don't need to include inline `script` via an attribute for the tag. Well... you wouldn't need it even if it was `Vanilla Javascript` anyway.

Comment: You don't have an element with `ID` _imagepopup_ in your markup.

Comment: I've tried display which also doesn't work. and yeah i've updated my code since then, that wasn't the problem

Comment: Please make sure that the code you present here is the current one and specially, the one that is causing you issues.

Comment: The live version of the website was updated 1 minute after the question posted, I guess you saw the question just before the site updated

Comment: That's another piece of advice. According to SO recommendations, please avoid links to off-site pages, as they can be updated constantly and won't reflect the current situation when another user looking for answers to a similar issue comes to your question.

Comment: I couldn't include all the html and css in the question as it would take up far too much space, that's why I included an off page link, as I said, it was updated within a minute of posting, I honestly didn't think someone would have even read it by then

Comment: Check this out: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 3):

You can make a div clickable in jquery with $("#myDiv").click(function() {dosomething();});

```
$(function() {
  $(".rectanglewrap").click(function() {
    $("#imagepopup").toggle(250);
  });
});
```